# Getting unique values with SUM and JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the total of calc.transport
Table 3_product_folder contains duplicate values (column 'folder_id'), how can I prevent the from messing up the SUM?
I have tried DISTINCT with no succes.

Any suggestions?

```
SELECT
SUM(calc.transport) AS transport
FROM 0_calculatie_id AS calc
LEFT JOIN 0_calculatie_inh_id AS id
ON id.calculatie_id = calc.id
LEFT JOIN 3_product_folder AS fld_id
ON fld_id.product_id = id.id
LEFT JOIN 4_folder_dossier AS fld
ON fld.product_folder_id = fld_id.folder_id
LEFT JOIN 10_factuur_inh AS fac_inh
ON fac_inh.folder_id = fld.id
LEFT JOIN 9_factuur_id AS fac
ON fac.id = fac_inh.factuur_id
WHERE YEAR(fac.datum_verstuurd) = ".$row['jaar']." AND MONTH(fac.datum_verstuurd) = ".$row_mth2['maand']."
```

I have tried this nested query but that not all items are calculated then:

```
SELECT
SUM(temp.transport) AS transport
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT
calc.transport,
fld_id.folder_id
FROM 0_calculatie_id AS calc
LEFT JOIN 0_calculatie_inh_id AS id
ON id.calculatie_id = calc.id
LEFT JOIN 3_product_folder AS fld_id
ON fld_id.product_id = id.id
LEFT JOIN 4_folder_dossier AS fld
ON fld.product_folder_id = fld_id.folder_id
LEFT JOIN 10_factuur_inh AS fac_inh
ON fac_inh.folder_id = fld.id
LEFT JOIN 9_factuur_id AS fac
ON fac.id = fac_inh.factuur_id
WHERE YEAR(fac.datum_verstuurd) = 2012 AND MONTH(fac.datum_verstuurd) = 7) AS temp
```

Comment: Have you tried nested selects like `SELECT SUM(...) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ... )`?

Comment: I have added an comment to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what the structure of the table?

you haven't grouped the SQL statement:

```
WHERE YEAR(fac.datum_verstuurd) = ".$row['jaar']." AND MONTH(fac.datum_verstuurd) = ".$row_mth2['maand']."
GROUP BY fld_id.product_id
```

Comment: That will give me an results grouped by item and noy by month and year

Comment: Move conditions to HAVING statement http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html